# How are the animations in the new about pages done?

Tags: discussion, tour

Sorry if this is not a question I should ask here, but:

the [new](https://stackoverflow.com/about) [about](https://askubuntu.com/about) [pages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/about) look really cool with those lazy-loaded animations and all. How are the animations like these done? Are they CSS3 or JS animations?

Comment: Definitely Javascript. :)

Comment: I have just earned the badge "informed" because of you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The page is directed using JavaScript (and jQuery).

It loads additional content as you scroll down and co-ordinates the animation. They aren't using CSS transitions, although some of the effects can be achieved with CSS too - but when you are loading the content and triggering animations all inside of jQuery, you might as well animate there too to keep it all in once place.

The JavaScript can bee seen in http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/about.js?v=6742560ee1f1

Comment: And tidiet here: http://jsfiddle.net/cgpQF/

Comment: Thanks @BramVanroy - much more readable :)

Answer (score 2):

The animation is trigged by the scrollTop value.

I would program this that way (JQuery of course :o) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Default values
    $('#myDiv1, #myDiv2').data('anim',false);

    $('body').scroll(function() {
        //Anim 1 : Check if the element position is reach and if the animation has already be done
        if(($(this).scrollTop() > 500)&&($(this).scrollTop() < 1000))
            if($('#myDiv1').data('anim') === false)
                $('#myDiv1').data('anim',true).animate({left: '-=100'});

        //Anim 2
        if(($(this).scrollTop() > 1000)&&($(this).scrollTop() < 1500))
            if($('#myDiv2').data('anim') === false)
                $('#myDiv2').data('anim',true).animate({left: '-=100'});
    });
});
```